# Is it possible to decrypt a file without knowing password only an encrypted string?

Tags: encryption, database, decryption

I am stuck at a point, here I have encryptionkeys.db(i don't know the use of a file). The folder name is also encrypted(coded) I know the folder name(decrypted), with this I just want to get the password and decrypt the simultaneous files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the encryption method used is vulnerable to a [Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). If so, it may be possible to retrieve the encryption keys, but this is unlikely as standards such as AES are resistant to this.